# Creating a form to search for records based on multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a form that allows you to return results based on multiple criteria.

I have `FirstName` field, `LastName` field, and `State` Field.

I also have an text boxes named `searchFirst`, `searchLast`, `searchState` where users can input criteria.

The search button will execute the following code once clicked.

```vb
Private Sub mySearchQuery_Click()

Dim filter As String

Dim rtFirstName As String
Dim rtLastName As String
Dim rtState As String

rtFirstName = Me.searchFirst.Value
rtLastName = Me.searchLast.Value
rtState = Me.searchState.Value

If Not IsNull(rtFirstName) Then
        If Not IsNull(filter) Then filter = filter & " AND "
        filter = filter & "(FirstName like""*" & rtFirstName & "*"")"
End If


If Not IsNull(rtLastName) Then
        If Not IsNull(filter) Then filter = filter & " AND "
        filter = filter & "(LastName like""*" & rtLastName & "*"")"
End If

If Not IsNull(rtState) Then
        If Not IsNull(filter) Then filter = filter & " AND "
        filter = filter & "(State LIKE""*" & rtState & "*"")"
End If

' Now re-construct the SQL query '
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * FROM MainData"

If Not IsNull(filter) Then
        sql = sql & " WHERE " & filter
End If

Me.RecordSource = sql
'SubForm.Form.RecordSource = sql

End Sub
```

I am getting the following error below.

> Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression 'AND (FirstName like"*tracy*") AND (lastName like"*Smith*")
>   AND (State LIKE"*ga*")'.

I am not sure why `AND` was included at the beginning of the search query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure why AND was included at the beginning of the search
>   query?

Since you have `Dim filter As String`, `filter` can never contain Null.  That means these `If` conditions ...  `If Not IsNull(filter)` ... will always be True.

Similarly, `Not IsNull(rtFirstName)`, `Not IsNull(rtLastName)`, and `Not IsNull(rtState)` will always be True.

The net result is the code adds another condition piece to your `filter` string regardless of whether or not the corresponding search text box contains anything, and each of those pieces is prefixed with `" AND "`.

With those points in mind, you could refactor your code to add a `filter` segment only when you have something in the corresponding search text box and decide when to include `" AND "`.  However I find it simpler to include `" AND "` for each of them and then strip away the very first `" AND "` from `filter` before adding it to the `WHERE` clause.

```vb
Private Sub mySearchQuery_Click()
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim strWhere As String

    If Len(Trim(Me!searchFirst.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND FirstName Like ""*" & Me!searchFirst.Value & "*"""
    End If

    If Len(Trim(Me!searchLast.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND LastName Like ""*" & Me!searchLast.Value & "*"""
    End If

    If Len(Trim(Me!searchState.Value) & vbNullString) > 0 Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND State Like ""*" & Me!searchState.Value & "*"""
    End If

    ' Now re-construct the SQL query
    strSelect = "SELECT * FROM MainData"

    ' only add WHERE clause if we have something in strWhere    
    If Len(strWhere) > 0 Then
        ' use Mid() to ignore leading " AND "
        strSelect = strSelect & " WHERE " & Mid(strWhere, 6)
    End If
    Debug.Print strSelect ' <- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there

    ' enable one of these RecordSource lines after confirming Debug.Print shows you what you need
    'Me.RecordSource = sql
    'SubForm.Form.RecordSource = sql
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Yup! that worked as intended. You saved my 5 hours of stress! Thank you Thank you!